# Check if a country code exists in a cell

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to check if a country code exists in a cell `country` before a user can add anything to the database. So, if a country code did not exist, he would not be able to add anything.

I'm storing country codes as comma separated values. The column type is VARCHAR.

```
"id"    "rtype" "country"
"1"     "0"     "US,UK,SE,CA"
"2"     "1"     "US"
"3"     "2"     "UK"
```

I ran the following query, but this results in no rows. Where am going wrong here? The problem is, this query needs to run with comma separated values as well as single values.

```
select id, rtype from test where id=1 and country in('US')
```

**Expected results**

```
id | rType
 1 |   0

select id, rtype from test where id=2 and country in('US')
```

**Expected results**

```
id | rType
 2 |   0
```

Comment: You should review your data model and consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database.

Comment: Totally agree with Wolf

Comment: Normalized it is. The first row is set by the admin. The rest are all which a user adds.

Comment: No, it is not even in first normal form as it has multivalued attributes. You should have a many-to-many relationship between country codes and what you call test. Check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) for more information on 1NF.

Comment: If it was normalized this wouldn't be a question. Your `country` column should contain only one country code per record to start approaching some form of normalization. Some Google searches on data modeling and normalization would yield some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT id, rtype FROM test
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('US', country) > 0
```

This is how the `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)` function works:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. [...] Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a really nice [Set Datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html). It is very efficient and can store till 64 distinct members of 255 values. I don't know if you could change your column type, but it would solve a lot of problems:

1. your column would be indexable
2. you wouldn't store duplicated values by mistake
3. it would be stored very efficiently
4. invalid values would be ignored (or error if in strict mode)
5. trailing spaces are removed

You'd search using the [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the country codes are the comma separated values , you can not directly use in .
You can you like instead.

select id, rtype from test where country like '%US%'

Comment: This would actually match other strings such as `SE,RUS,ARG`